# How to show message for a certain time in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I'm displaying a message when the user clicks on the button.

I want to show this message for 10 seconds and then hide it.

My code is the following:

```
<script>
  function Ctrl($scope, $window) {
    $scope.greeting = 'Hello, World!';
    $scope.doGreeting = function() {
       $scope.msg="hi";
    };
  }
</script>
<div ng-controller="Ctrl">
  <input type="text" ng-model="greeting" />
    <button ng-click="doGreeting()">click</button>
    {{msg}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 7):

You can set a variable that determines whether to show the message or not and hide it and after 10,000 seconds. You will have to inject $timeout as shown below. Then in your view you will need to wrap `{{msg}}` in a span in order to use `ng-show`

```
<script>
  function Ctrl($scope, $window, $timeout) {
    $scope.greeting = 'Hello, World!';
    $scope.showGreeting = false;
    $scope.doGreeting = function() {
       $scope.msg="hi";
       $scope.showGreeting = true;
       $timeout(function(){
          $scope.showGreeting = false;
       }, 10000);
    };
  }
</script>
<div ng-controller="Ctrl">
  <input type="text" ng-model="greeting" />
  <button ng-click="doGreeting()">click</button>
  <span ng-show="showGreeting ">{{msg}}</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The way I did to show a message for a certain time in angularjs was using **[AngularJS-Toaster](https://github.com/jirikavi/AngularJS-Toaster)** library

To use the library follow this steps:

```
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angularjs-toaster/0.4.9/toaster.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular.min.js" ></script>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.0/angular-animate.min.js" ></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angularjs-toaster/0.4.9/toaster.min.js"></script>
```

Add toaster container directive:

```
<toaster-container></toaster-container>
```

Prepare the call of toaster method:

```
// Display an info toast with no title
    angular.module('main', ['toaster'])
    .controller('myController', function($scope, toaster) {
        $scope.pop = function(){
            toaster.pop('success', "title", "text");
        };
    });
```

Call controller method on button click:

```
<div ng-controller="myController">
    <button ng-click="pop()">Show a Toaster</button>
</div>
```

Here you can see a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Rv5qgW?p=preview) showing many kinds of toasts showing differents messages

Answer (score 0):

Add the [$timeout](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24timeout) dependency to your controller.  Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nQqLk/1/):

```html
<div ng-app>
    <div ng-controller="Ctrl">
        <input type="text" ng-model="greeting" />
        <button ng-click="doGreeting()">click</button>
        <div class="ng-hide" ng-show="showMessage">{{msg}} {{ greeting }}</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
function Ctrl($scope, $window, $timeout) {
    var messageTimer = false,
        displayDuration = 5000; // milliseconds (5000 ==> 5 seconds)

    $scope.showMessage = false;
    $scope.msg = "hi";

    $scope.doGreeting = function () {
        if (messageTimer) {
            $timeout.cancel(messageTimer);
        }

        $scope.showMessage = true;

        messageTimer = $timeout(function () {
            $scope.showMessage = false;
        }, displayDuration);
    };
}
```